# Remove sequence from string if preceded by same sequence

Tags: ruby, regex

I have some sequences in a string denoted by "@number" (/@\d/)
I want to remove any redundant sequences, where @2 is followed by @2, 
I only want to remove them if another identical @number sequence is found directly after somewhere in the text, so for `@2lorem@2ipsum` the 2nd @2 is removed, but for `@2lorem@1ipsum@2dolor` nothing is removed because @1 is between the two @2 sequences.

```
"@2randomtext@2randomtext@2randomtext@1bla@2bla2@2bla2"
```

becomes:

```
"@2randomtextrandomtextrandomtext@1bla@2bla2bla2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"@2randomtext@2randomtext@2randomtext@1bla@2bla2@2bla2".gsub /(?<=(@\d))([^@]*)\1/,'\2'
=> "@2randomtextrandomtextrandomtext@1bla@2bla2bla2"
```

Comment: You sir are the master of regex. +1

Comment: You will get into trouble this way with strings such as '@2foo@22bar'

Comment: @pguardiario, as I understand, you mean, that `@22 != @2`, but as I see in question, `(/@\d/)` means a single digit. I get `"@2foo2bar"`, is it wrong?

Comment: Possibly. It's possible that this solution is good enough, it's really not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can split it into tokens:

```
my_string = "@2randomtext@2randomtext@2randomtext@1bla@2bla2@2bla2"
tokens = my_string.scan /(@\d+)?((?:(?!@\d+).)*)/
#=> [["@2", "randomtext"], ["@2", "randomtext"], ["@2", "randomtext"], ["@1", "bla"], ["@2", "bla2"], ["@2", "bla2"]]
```

Then chunk, map and join:

```
tokens.chunk{|x| x[0].to_s}.map{|n, v| [n, v.map(&:last)]}.join
#=> "@2randomtextrandomtextrandomtext@1bla@2bla2bla2"
```

Comment: Beautiful, any answer that doesn't need a throwaway variable is my preferred answer. You've also given me something new to learn, never come across chunk before!

Comment: Because `.chunk` appeared only in 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

```
my_string = "@2randomtext@2randomtext@2randomtext@1bla@2bla2@2bla2"

prev_sequence = String.new
penultimate_index = my_string.length - 2

for i in 0..penultimate_index
  if my_string[i] == '@'
    new_sequence = "@#{my_string[i+1]}"
    if new_sequence == prev_sequence
      my_string.slice!( i, 2 )
    else 
      prev_sequence = new_sequence
    end
  end
end


puts my_string
```

Answer (score -1):

easy... split your string into an array, and then compare the number that comes right after that. If it's the same, remove it/them. The complicated (through not that much), is that you can't remove entries from an array while looping through them... so what you need to do is make a recursive function... here's the pseudo:

-= Global values =-
Decalre StringArray and set it to OriginalString.SplitOn("@")

-= Method RemoveLeadingDuplicates =-
Declare Counter
Declare RemoveIndex
loop for each string in StringArray
  if previous lead == current lead
    Set RemoveIndex
    break from loop
  else
    previous lead = current lead
Increase Counter By 1
end loop

if RemoveIndex is not null
  Remove the item at specified index from the array
  Call RemoveLeadingDuplicates

Return